# Facebook api rate limit - server side or client side is better?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, limit

i'm developping a web-based application that implement facebook login process to identify user and ask for their info using facebook graph API.

The question is which is better between server side and client side implementation in term of api rate limitation. For all the documentations and discussions i'have read there's a limit of 600 calls per 600 seconds, is that count per ip or per access_token or per application key? Is that better to implement all the api call on client side to not to reach the limit rate?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you do rate limiting yourself, you have the possibility to give priority to "important" requests, if you let Facebook do it, you won't have that control. Weigh that against simplicity and you'll have a pretty good idea what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#features):

> If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds
>   please contact us by creating a [confidential bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create) report with the
>   "threshold policy" tag as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M
>   MAU) or (***>100M API calls per day***) or (>50M impressions per day).

If you think you would pass the 100-million-API-call-per-day limit then contact Facebook.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this on, totally forgot about this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Querying API rate limit are on application basis. But you should understand that querying API and Authorizing user isn't the same thing, I can't prove this but it's hard to believe that authorization flow is somehow limited (look on very big apps and games which have millions of daily uses)...

Decision on how authorization flow should be implemented in your app (Client or Server Side) should be based on many factors such as technology you use, language your application written in, your knowledge, etc... This is very subjective.

I personally prefer client side flow using JS-SDK due to ease of implementation and passion to JavaScript, but again this is subjective...

Comment: I believe that authorization flow is not limited too but i'm wonder if its also count when i'm querrying the API with facebook Javascript SDK, it means that all queries to the graph come from my client's ip.

Comment: I'm using php and javascript, my site has a facebook connect button that allow user to connect. I'm gonna have more than 100k user who use the button per hour, and each time users click the button, i make at leats one call to the graph API. Therfor i'm asking for a workaround solution to not to reach the 100k limit per 24hours...